# Node creation in Linked list in c++

Tags: c++, linked-list

```cpp
class node{
    public:
    int data;
    node* next;
    node(int val){
       data=val;
       next=NULL;
    }
};
```

For this class, the object creation statement is `node* n=new node(5);`

Why do we need to add the `*` after `node`? What will happen if I write `node n=new node(5)`?

Are they both the same?

Comment: This is really something any decent text-book, tutorial or class should have taught you. If not then you should consider using some other book, tutorial or class. [Here's a list of decent books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: *"What will happen if i write `node n=new node(5)`?"* -- try it and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do we need to add the `*` after `node`?

`new` returns a pointer to the memory that was allocated, in this case a `node` instance, so you need a (`node*`) pointer variable to receive the returned memory address (of the `node` instance).

> What will happen if I write `node n=new node(5)`?

The code will fail to compile, since `n` is not a (`node*`) pointer.